# How to create a border for SCNNode to indicate its selection in iOS 11 ARKit-Scenekit?

Tags: scenekit, ios11, arkit, xcode9beta6

How to draw a border to highlight a SCNNode and indicate to user that the node is selected?
In my project user can place multiple virtual objects and user can select any object anytime. Upon selection i should show the user highlighted 3D object. Is there a way to directly achieve this or draw a border over SCNNode?

Comment: Little hack: open Xcode, create a new project from the `SceneKit` template, open the VC, scroll down. You'll see code for highlighting a node when tapping it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to add a tap gesture recognizer to the `sceneView`.

```
// add a tap gesture recognizer
let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleTap(_:)))
scnView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
```

Then, handle the tap and highlight the node:

```
@objc
func handleTap(_ gestureRecognize: UIGestureRecognizer) {
    // retrieve the SCNView
    let scnView = self.view as! SCNView

    // check what nodes are tapped
    let p = gestureRecognize.location(in: scnView)
    let hitResults = scnView.hitTest(p, options: [:])
    // check that we clicked on at least one object
    if hitResults.count > 0 {
        // retrieved the first clicked object
        let result = hitResults[0]

        // get its material
        let material = result.node.geometry!.firstMaterial!

        // highlight it
        SCNTransaction.begin()
        SCNTransaction.animationDuration = 0.5

        // on completion - unhighlight
        SCNTransaction.completionBlock = {
            SCNTransaction.begin()
            SCNTransaction.animationDuration = 0.5

            material.emission.contents = UIColor.black

            SCNTransaction.commit()
        }

        material.emission.contents = UIColor.red

        SCNTransaction.commit()
    }
}
```

The snippet above highlights the whole node. You'd have to adjust it to highlight the borders only, if that's what you're looking for.

**Disclaimer:**
This code was taken directly from Xcode's template code created when opening a new game (`SceneKit`) project.

Comment: Since i am new to scenekit can you please let me know how to highlight the border alone?

Comment: What if I have more than one child node? Then I if you tap in multiple child nodes, different different child nodes get highlighted.

Comment: Of course, because this code highlights the one that was tapped!